# How do aliens without the Medicine Skill stop the bleeding condition?

Tags: skills, conditions, starfinder

According to Starfinder's bleeding condition rules:

> You take the listed amount of damage at the beginning of your turn each round until this condition ends. Your bleeding can be stopped with a successful DC 15 Medicine check as a standard action, or through the application of any ability that restores Hit Points.

Some aliens have innate capabilities that allow them to restore hit points and can stop the bleeding in this way. Other aliens have the Medicine skill (or an ally with the Medicine skill) and can thus stop the bleeding that way. But how do unintelligent monsters, or aliens that simply have no medical training stop the bleeding condition? Are they doomed if they get the bleeding condition and don't have some capable healer at hand to stop the bleeding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They might die before they can stop the bleeding, but they have a chance.

Medicine is usually a "trained only" skill, but the First Aid use of Medicine, which allows you to stabilize the dying and stop bleeding, specifies that it can be used untrained and is a static DC of 15, so even someone with no training and a -5 Wisdom modifier (1 Wisdom score) can succeed on a natural 20.  (SFRPG pg 143)